# border-radius on parent element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to display a whole container with all its content as a circle? I don't want the child elements displayed as circle on their own, but as a whole.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rg906ku/2/)

---

Solved Edit:

Thanks guys, "(overflow: hidden}" solved it.

[Fiddle of what I wanted to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/2rg906ku/6/)

Comment: Google is your Friend

Comment: I didn't find anything relevant..

Comment: You are close. Just use `#container { overflow:hidden; }` and tinker with your height.

Comment: @Robbsen You should also include your full code in the question, not just in the fiddle. Most of the confusion and negativity seems to stem from the fact that people do not see that you have already used border-radius.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2rg906ku/4/ ... ?

Comment: @karthikr There's nothing circular about the contents of that Fiddle

Comment: @Marcelo yes I get that. Will do that the next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [box-sizing : border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when
>   the document is in Quirks mode. Note: Padding & border will be inside
>   of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px
>   solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 350px;}

[overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.

and `border-radius: 50%`

```
#container {
border-radius: 50%
overflow:hidden;
}
```

here is a demo

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: #ccc
}
#container{
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  padding: 70px; /*you need this to keep all child visible (horizontally)*/
  background: white;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what your changes are accomplishing?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the Question Title you Need to use CSS `border-radius`

you need to set it to 50%

By the Way: I just Googled `CSS Circle` and ths was my first Entry: http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles
Wich exactly stetes how to

Comment: This does not have any effect on OP's Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I created a JS Fiddle for you (http://jsfiddle.net/4w18xt5v/)

Let me know if this is what you meant?

//CSS

```
#container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
#header{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
}
#content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for the OP, if you tell im what `display:flex` ans `justfiy-Content:` mean and why its in the Code. Yor Fiddle is good to Show that it works but nor really how

Answer (score -1):

If what you're trying to do is turn your rectangles into circles, just add `border-radius: 100%` to your CSS code.

Comment: border-radius 100% won't make a circle